# Will self-deleted, 0-scored, unanswered questions count against us?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, post-ban

If I have too many self-deleted, 0-score, unanswered questions, could that result in a question-ban? Or in general, can quality bans be applied due to self-deleted, zero-scored, unanswered posts? Maybe if we ask a low quality question because of lack of research so the premise is bad, so we can't edit it, maybe deleting it before the community expresses disapproval would be a final chance to think better of my question?

Comment: Nobody knows. It's a secret. Instead of focusing on what will cause a question ban or rate limit, why not focus on how to improve the questions?

Comment: @SamuelLiew Sometimes, if the premise of the question is bad, like if I ask something that I could have googled, there isn't much that editing can do. What can I do with such questions?

Comment: Seems like zero-scored unanswered deleted answers wouldn't count, according to the linked dupe.

Comment: @SamuelLiew I tend to read that answer as "zero scores by themselves will not get you banned". I'd be very surprised if they don't count at all. (1x -1 +10x 0) will probably get one banned even if most of their posts are zero score.